# Unique brazilian CPF

Tags: testrigor

How can I create a unique brazilian CPF using the tool testRigor?

I'm trying the command:

generate unique cpf, then enter in "CPF" and save as "generatedCpf"

But it isn't working because the cpf is not a brazilian cpf.

I want to receive a brazilian unique cpf using that command.

like "xxx.xxx.xxx-xx" or without .-

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Have you read the specification for how these numbers are generated? The last two digits are algorithmically generated from the first nine. If you generate nine random digits, you can mathematically determine the last two.

Answer (score 0):

testRigor has already a built-in words only to generate unique email or unique name.
You can try:

generate from template "###-###-###-##", then enter into "CPF" and save as "generatedCPF"

But there is no guarantee this would be a valid CPF, validating a CPF is not possible with built-in functionality.